# X-editable with .Net and c# web methods

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webmethod

I am using [X-Editable Plugin](http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/index.html) in Asp.net.
I have tried this: [Usage with .Net and C# Webmethods](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/issues/19)
But it gives me error. It is not calling the WebMethod as it should be.

How to solve this problem?
Please help.

Javascript:

```
 $('#username').editable({
     url: function (params) {                      
        return $.ajax({
           url: 'Default.aspx/TestMethod',
           data: JSON.stringify(params),
           dataType: 'json',
           async: true,
           cache: false,
           timeout: 10000,
           success: function (response) {
                     alert("Success");
           },
           error: function () {
                     alert("Error in Ajax");
           }
          });
      }
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="username" class="myeditable">superuser</a>
```

WebMethod in Default.aspx:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static String TestMethod(String params)
{
    //access params here
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to call a page method, first of all you need to make a request of type *POST* (also having content-type set will not do any harm):

```
$('#username').editable({
    url: function (params) {                      
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Default.aspx/TestMethod',
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error in Ajax");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Also the JSON will be auto deserialized on server side, so you should expect the `name`, `pk` and `value` parameters on server side (this is what plugin is sending according to [docs](http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/docs.html))

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static String TestMethod(string name, string pk, string value)
{
    //access params here
}
```

In your case the `pk` will be null as you haven't set one.

Comment: thank you tpeczek. I wasnt provided the TYPE for Ajax call. Also thanks for the Signature of WebMehthod.

Comment: +1 Btw can I use PUT ? As PUT is meant to 'update' and POST is for 'add new'. I'm using REST approach here.

Comment: @Roylee I'm afraid that there is no way to change the supported verb on the ASP.NET side, you would have to go for HttpHandler instead.

Comment: THanks @tpeczek. Yes I managed to get it working with WEB API（REST). Just hack using ajaxOption and you could achieve PUT easily.